# What determines the growth of a tree in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have seen trees 1 block wide and some that are 4 wide and have a huge canopy.  What determines the growth of the bigger trees?  Is it the space between each planted sapling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree#Growth_and_characteristics) has quite a bit of information about how trees grow in Minecraft. Basically, a sapling will attempt to grow at random levels. When it makes this attempt, it randomly chooses a tree configuration based on its type and then if it can grow in that configuration it does.

Jungle trees are a special case because if four jungle saplings are arranged in a 2 by 2 pattern on the ground, then if the area is open enough they will grow into a 2 by 2 tree. These trees can also spawn naturally in jungle biomes.

Comment: Also see the [tree farming entry](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Tree_farming) for more info.